# How to absolute postion text to the bottom of the page but not viewport?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a page where footer have:

```
postion: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

it work fine when height of the window is larger then the content, but when it's smaller then the content the footer show above the text. I try to put

```
body {
    min-height: 550px;
}
```

but this don't fix the issue, I can scroll but the footer is align to the bottom of the viewport, (on android the footer is chaning to the bottom of the window when I scroll).

Is it possible to align footer to the bottom of the page when there are scrollbars?

Here is my [page](http://jcubic.pl/test/).

Comment: must it be absolutely positioned? If you remove absolute position and place the footer at the end of the markup It will be positioned at the bottom of your content - even if contetn exceeds the viewport

Comment: Add `position:relative` to you `body`: http://jsfiddle.net/KjBFu/ ?

Comment: @Passerby great thanks it work, add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `<body>` to make footer position itself according to `<body>`, not `<html>` or viewport:

```css
body {
    position:relative;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KjBFu/) and use the "toggle" button to toggle `<body>` between relatively positioned and statically positioned and observe the different.

This is because `position:absolute` element position itself base on the deepest parent that "knows" its position. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> A **positioned element** is an element whose computed position property is `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correct

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CSS Layout Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { 
    margin:0; padding:0; 
    height:100%; 
    font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
}

.container { width:900px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; }
.body { min-height:100%; position:relative; }

/**
 * padding-bottom -> the "computed" height of the footer (height + padding).
 * In this example 20 + 10 + 10 = 40 (height + padding-top + padding-bottom)
 */
.main { padding-bottom:40px; }

.header { background-color:#006600; color:#FFFFFF; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px; }
.page { background-color:#CCCCCC; padding:10px; }

.footer { position:absolute; bottom:0; display:block; width:100%; z-index:1000; }
.footer .container { 
    background-color:#000000; color:#FFFFFF; 
    padding:10px; height:20px; 
}

</style>
</head>

<body><div class="body">
    <div class="main container">
        <div class="header"><strong>Header</strong></div>
        <div class="page">Page content</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container"><strong>Footer</strong> <em>always at bottom ;) </em></div>
    </div>

</div></body>
</html>
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sEks6/) and [post](http://pbaris.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/html-css-footer-always-at-bottom/)